# Extract int value and string from string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, integer

I would like to use string class, to extract some information from the string.
Given the string: <12,Apple>,<20,Orange>,<49,iPhone>

I would like to let 12, 20, 49 to a int array.
that means a[0] = 12, a[1] = 20, a[2] = 49.

And let Apple, Orange, iPhone to a String array.
that means b[0] = "Apple", b[1] = "Orange" b[2] = "iPhone"

How should I do?

Comment: Does my pseudo-code help you to understand what you should do? Basically you need to extract each punctuation position, and then extract the strings using those positions. If the value of the string is an integer, you can using `atoi` function to convert the string to an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the string follows the format `<int,string>,...`. Please find the pseudo-code below:

```
Loop through the string `str` and
{
    smaller_sign_pos = str.find('<', prev_pos)
    entry_comma_pos = str.find(',', smaller_sign_pos+1)
    greater_sign_pos = str.find('>', entry_comma_pos+1)

    if (all pos values are not `npos`)
    {
        int_value = atoi(str.substr(smaller_sign_pos+1, entry_comma_pos-smaller_sign_pos-1))
        str_value = str.substr(entry_comma_pos+1, greater_sign_pos-entry_comma_pos-1)
        prev_pos = greater_sign_pos+1
        append int_value to int array
        append str_value to string array
        optional: you can check if the comma after '>' exists
    }
    else
    {
        break or set the end of loop flag
    }
}
```